# Unable to insert data into models using DRF due to TypeError Object of type IntegrityError is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a form-data which I want to insert into two different models. So at first I created both the models as shown below -

This is the model **User**.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique= True)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, unique= True)
    password = models.TextField(blank=False)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Businesses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):

        return 'User Object ({})'.format(self.id)
```

This is the model **DeliveryAgent**.

```
class DeliveryAgentVehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle_model = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    year_of_make = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    vehicle_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='vehicle_photo/', max_length=None, null=True, blank=False)
    driver_license = models.ImageField(upload_to='driver_license/', max_length=None, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return 'DeliveryAgentVehicle Object ({})'.format(self.id)
```

[image: This is my form-data]

Then I created **APIView** called **DeliveryAPIView()**.

In this view at first I have declared ***parser_classes***. Then in post method I updated request.data  dictionary by adding key as a role and `id` (of role `Delivery_agent`) as value. I did this so that this view would only create user of type `Delivery_Agent`

```
class DeliveryAPIView(APIView):

    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        request.data['role'] = Role.objects.get(role_name='Delivery_agent').id

        deserialized_data = DeliverySerializer(data=request.data)

        if deserialized_data.is_valid():
            try:
                delivery_agent = deserialized_data.save()
            except IntegrityError as identifier:
                return Response(identifier)
        return Response({
            "message":"Done"
        })
```

As I want to store the form-data into two different model, I have splited `validate_data` dictionary into two saperate dictionaries `delivey_agent_vehicle` and `delivery_agent` in serializer.

To map the vehicle details with the delivery agent I first need to have the `user_id` of delivery agent. So to create delivery agent I had to pass dictionary `delivey_agent` to `create_user()` method which belongs to `User` model's manager. Then expecting that it will create delivery agent and return a string representation instance of the delivery agent I called `create()` method of `DeliveryAgentVehicle` to insert the vehicle details of the delivery agent.

This is how my serializer look like -

```
class DeliverySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    phone_number = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    role = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    vehicle_model = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    year_of_make = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    photo_of_vehicle = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False)
    driver_license = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        validated_data['role'] = Role.objects.get(pk=validated_data['role'])

        delivey_agent={}

        delivey_agent['email'] = validated_data['email']
        delivey_agent['password'] = validated_data['password']
        delivey_agent['first_name'] = validated_data['first_name']
        delivey_agent['last_name'] = validated_data['last_name']
        delivey_agent['phone_number'] = validated_data['phone_number']
        delivey_agent['role'] = validated_data['role']

        agent_id = User.objects.create_user(**delivey_agent)

        delivey_agent_vehicle={}

        delivey_agent_vehicle['vehicle_model'] = validated_data['vehicle_model']
        delivey_agent_vehicle['vehicle_model'] = validated_data['year_of_make']
        delivey_agent_vehicle['vehicle_model'] = validated_data[ 'photo_of_vehicle']
        delivey_agent_vehicle['vehicle_model'] = validated_data['driver_license']
        delivey_agent_vehicle['user'] = agent_id

        agent_vehicle_id = DeliveryAgentVehicle.objects.create(**delivey_agent_vehicle)

        print(delivey_agent_vehicle)
        print(delivey_agent)

        return agent_id
```

This is the error which it has returned -

```
Internal Server Error: /users/delivery/signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 103, in render
    allow_nan=not self.strict, separators=separators
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 67, in default
    return super().default(obj)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type IntegrityError is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
        try:
            delivery_agent = deserialized_data.save()
        except IntegrityError as identifier:
            return Response(identifier)
```

Response expects a JSON serializable object to return to the user which is usually the serializer data, a dictionary. However, you're passing it the `IntegrityError` object that you catch.

If you want to return the raw DB error message to the client(which is not advisable), you should do something like this instead:

```
try:
    delivery_agent = deserialized_data.save()
except IntegrityError as identifier:
    return Response({
        "message":str(identifier)
    }, status=400)
```